# Using C (syscall) to write an integer matrix into a text file?

Tags: c, matrix, system-calls

So, I have my matrix, let's say
**int matC[N][N],**
which is already filled with integer values.

What I have to do is to save this matrix into a .txt file.
I've tried this:

1: convert the integers contained in the matrix into a string

```
char *buffer;
for (int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0 ; j < N ; j++)
    {
        snprintf(buffer, sizeof(matC[i][j]), "%d", matC[i][j]);
    }
}
```

2: write the string in a file (fileC.txt)

```
int fdC = open("fileC.txt", O_RDWR);
write(fdC, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```

I do get something in my fileC.txt, but it's some sort of bunch of unintelegible symbols.
Thanks in anticipation for any help.

Comment: All your `snprintf` calls are overwriting the same 4 (maybe some other number depending on your system) bytes in the beginning of your buffer.

Comment: You'll need to allocate memory for the buffer, and `sizeof` a pointer is just that, the size of the pointer, not the allocated memory.

Comment: You're passing the wrong `sizeof` to `snprintf` : it's supposed to be the size of the target buffer, which isn't necessarily the size of the thing that you're printing.

Comment: After you write the integer values `1`, `2`, and `34` to the file, how are you going to tell the difference between `1`, `2`, `34` and `12`, `3`, `4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things.

First, you need to allocate memory for your buffer. `sizeof(buffer)` will be the size of a pointer, not the buffer length, so you you store that in `buf_len`. Depending on how many digits the numbers in your matrix are, you might need more or less space in your buffer.

Then, you don't want to write to the beginning of `buffer` with each `snprintf` call, but `strchr(buffer, '\0')` will return a pointer to the spot you want to write to. The second argument should be the length of the buffer from the spot you're currently at, which is `buf_len - strlen(buffer)`.

Finally, you only want to write `strlen(buffer)` bytes to the file so you don't write random bytes to your file.

```
char    *buffer;
int     buf_len = 100;


buffer = (char*)malloc(buf_len);
buffer[0] = '\0';
for (int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0 ; j < N ; j++)
    {
        snprintf(strchr(buffer, '\0'), buf_len - strlen(buffer), "%d", matC[i][j]);
    }
}

int fdC = open("fileC.txt", O_RDWR);
write(fdC, buffer, strlen(buffer));
free(buffer);
```

Comment: Given `buffer = (char*)malloc(buf_len);`, both `strchr(buffer, '\0')` and `strlen(buffer)` are undefined behavior.